# Front Panel Audio is not working in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, headphones, front-panel

I currently upgraded to windows 8 and my asus A45V laptop's audio front panel is not working.The sound driver is Realtek. So,I downloaded the windows 8 driver from Asus website and installed it.Still not working.I uninstall and try again.No Luck! The laptop speaker is working well but not headphones. I googled a lot and the solutions from most forum didn't help my problem.
Any ideas!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you manually right-click the volume icon, go to Playback Devices and set the headphones as default, does it work?

Comment: It only shows Digital Audio(HDMI) and Speakers(Default Device).The headphone doesn't show up.I also believe it's not the hardware problem.because this audio panel works well with my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

also look at the realtek website see if they have posted anything for the audio driver. These won't be tested by asus but it shouldn't be any real issue you can't roll back too.

Comment: I already tried several version of Realtek HD audio manager.both from Asus website and realtek website.Nothing works!! I think the problem is windows 8.